# Closing BufferedWriter/Reader affects other instances bound to the same socket?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have 'n' server threads, and each one listen to 1 client.

When a server thread receives a message from its client, it needs to notify the other 'n-1' clients, and that's the reason why I keep a shared object (containing an array of 'n' sockets, one for each client) between the server threads.

Moreover, in the main server thread that holds the `ServerSocket`, every time I accept a new connection with a client I open a `BufferedWriter/Reader` to give a first answer to him using the new socket returned from `ServerSocket.accept()`.

In case of an "OK" answer I open a new thread passing the new socket to it, in order to listen to the new client's following requests.

The problem is that i cannot close the `BufferedReader` and the `BufferedWriter` in the main server thread, because it will also close the underlying stream, causing problems to the server thread that is listening to that socket/stream.

And the question: if I open another `BufferedReader` (bound to the same socket) in the new thread, and then close it, will other `BufferedReaders(Writers)` ( specifically the ones opened in the main server thread, that i couldn't close before ) opened on the same socket be closed? Will an exception be thrown on them?

It could be possible to share the opened `BufferedReader / Writer` instead of the socket, to avoid instantiating every time a new object, but this is a question related to what could happen if i do things in the way described above.

Please tell me if I hadn't been clear, my english is not really good.

Comment: I would recomment sharing nothing from the *main* thread and further threads. Every thread should maintain its data in their own scope, and you will be free of any chaotic issue.

Comment: You can't reliably have more than one `BufferedReader`/`BufferedWriter` on the same stream. Doesn't matter whether they're on the same thread or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Closing any Reader or Writer or stream wrapped around a stream closes the wrapped stream.
2. Closing either the input stream or the output stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket.
3. Closing the socket closes both streams.

   In other words closing any of it closes all of it.
4. As noted in comments, multiple buffered streams/Readers/Writers wrapped around a single stream cannot work.
5. Multiple threads reading from/writing to the same socket is unlikely to work correctly either, unless you take great care with synchronization and buffering.
6. You should not do any I/O with an accepted socket in the accept loop. Otherwise you can block, which affects further clients.

You need to rethink your design.

Comment: i am looking into something similar about the order of closing streams wrapping a socket, i was going to ask the question but you answer it here in #3. Do you have a source for that claim? i haven't found anything

Comment: @Hilikus The source is the Javadoc, first place you looked. In any case nothing else makes sense. How can the streams remain open when the socket is closed?

Answer (score 1):

Each Socket with an open connection to another Socket has an open InputStream and an open OutputStream. Closing either one of these streams will also close the socket. Closing a socket or its streams will not affect other sockets unless they are connected. You don't want to close any streams unless you also want to close the connection between the sockets using the streams. Please ask if there is something i missed or if you have other questions :)

Comment: Maybe i have not understood your answer, but i'm talking about closing readers/writers bound to the Same socket, so, if i'm not wrong, they are sharing the same stream. I will edit my question to be clearer

Comment: You cannot have different readers/writers bound to the same socket, only their input/output streams, although I wouldn't recommend doing so. And closing a buffered reader/writer will also close the stream which it buffers (the socket's), but it will also affect any other buffered readers/writers buffering that same stream, since it is now closed.

Comment: Closing the socket closes both streams, why almost in every example on the internet close them spratlly?